# Cannot calculate the perfect distance using vincentyGreatCircleDistance in PHP

Tags: php

I could not calculate the perfect distance using PHP. My code is below.

```
$latitudeTo=20.296599;
$longitudeTo=85.859779;
$latitude=20.296599;
$longitude=85.859779;
$distance=vincentyGreatCircleDistance($latitude,$longitude,$latitudeTo,$longitudeTo);
$dis=round($distance,2).'Km';

echo $dis;

function vincentyGreatCircleDistance($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo){
        $earthRadius=6371;
        $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
        $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
        $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
        $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

        $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;
        $a = pow(cos($latTo) * sin($lonDelta), 2) +
        pow(cos($latFrom) * sin($latTo) - sin($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta), 2);
        $b = sin($latFrom) * sin($latTo) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta);

        $angle = atan2(sqrt($a), $b);
        return $angle * $earthRadius;
    }
```

Here I am trying to calculate the distance between two lat long value. I am getting the below warning message.

```
 deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in
```

I am getting the output which echo prints is `9575.8Km` which is totally wrong. I need here to calculate the right distance and warning message should remove.